# CentOS - lsblk showing added new space for mpath, but pvdisplay is showing previous space

Tags: centos7, lvm, storage-spaces

Team,
I am working in a production environment and stumbled into a case where, a 3TB space from Storage has already been mounted and used for particular volume group called "**ipdata_vg**". Now at Storage end, I have expanded the space from 3T to 5T and the same has been observed in **mpathh** (using command **lsblk**), as seen below.

```
    sdm                       8:192  0    5T  0 disk
      └─mpathh                253:4    0    5T  0 mpath
        └─ipdata_vg-ipdata_lv 253:15   0    3T  0 lvm   /var/opt/mssql/ipdata
```

Now, the "**pvdisplay**" command is showing only 3T and no free PE is available:

```
--- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/mpathh
  VG Name               ipdata_vg
  PV Size               3.00 TiB / not usable 0
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              786431
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          786431
  PV UUID               9r5Nes-uM1v-D5PP-0mB4-dU4u-d7Sz-AwNf7U
```

Can someone please guide on how to make the PV Size to have full 5T, so that I can extend my volume group and logical volume to use a total space of 5T effectively. The file system used is **xfs**. The **vgdisplay** command output is as below:

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ipdata_vg
  System ID             namechangehere
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  85
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <3.00 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              786431
  Alloc PE / Size       786431 / <3.00 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               DBZ781-xxxx-dX0Z-yyyy-62XB-zzzz-2RmlhX
```

1. Will pvscan or pvresize /dev/mapper/mpathh do the job? I am not confident on executing this in production environment. plz suggest.